# Is there an 'unlock all' cheat in Burnout 3?

Tags: cheats, burnout-3

I am way too lazy to grind for everything and just want everything unlocked.

Is there a cheat for this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a cheat to unlock all vehicles. While on the screen to choose your vehicle, type in:

> Y, Y, Y, Y, X, Y, Y, Y, X, X, Y, X

to unlock them all.

I found this via searching, although the [original source is in French](http://www.jeuxvideo.com/wikis-soluce-astuces/tous-les-vehicules/221146). I don't know if this works, but it is the only cheat I found on the Internet.

For a walkthrough on how to unlock specs in the normal way, here is a [guide on IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/burnout-3-takedown/Xbox_Cheats) (too long to copy content here).